# Check if browser supports session storage by using sessionStorage property of window

Tags: javascript

```
(function(){
        if(typeof(window.sessionStorage) !== "undefined"){
            alert("This browser implements session storage");
        } 
        else{
            alert("This browser doesn't implement session storage");
        } 
    })();
```

//but i get an error 0:unspecified error on the console when this code is executed

[image]

Comment: It works for me in Chrome 86. How are you running it?

Comment: i'm runing it in edge

Comment: use a try...catch

Comment: I've tried above code in Chrome 86, Edge 86, IE 11 and they all work. Which browser did you run?

Comment: did try..catch, still an unspecified error. Is there a way to make it work on edge 44?

Comment: i guess my edge browser needs updating then. Thanks @namgold.

Comment: You shouldn't update your browser. The code above should run in all browser. Could you update the question with a screenshot of error?

Comment: @KarinaPadayhag "Edge 44" isn't a thing. Edge jumped from version 18 to version 79 when it became a Chromium-based browser.

Comment: @KarinaPadayhag Please post a screenshot of your entire Console window. I think you're entering the command incorrectly - or something else is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you set your browser to prevent the storage of cookies, simply getting the `sessionStorage` property may throw an error.

In Chrome the error message in this case is a bit clearer than yours:

> Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

You thus need to handle this exception in your code.
But there are also cases where an exception would only get thrown when actually trying to set a value (e.g IIRC some Safari versions in private mode). So for your test to actually work you even need to try setting a value, and while we're at it, why not check that the gotten value is indeed the one we did set.

So all in all, the full test goes like:

```js
// in StackSnippets sessionStorage is blocked
// so everyone should have the no-support alert here
(function(){
  let support = false;
  try {
    const rand = Math.random();
    support = typeof window.sessionStorage !== "undefined" &&
      (sessionStorage.test_support = rand),
      (sessionStorage.test_support === rand);
    sessionStorage.removeItem("test_support");
  }
  catch( e ) {
    support = false;
  }
  if(support){
    alert("This browser implements session storage");
  } 
  else{
    alert("This browser doesn't implement session storage");
  } 
})();
```

And [in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnt5muac/) where `sessionStorage` is normally allowed.